# Adding a key with values to a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to make a residual plot for a bunch of different filters. I have around 23 filters to worry about so 23 plots in total. Each plot is supposed to be residual value vs redshift of a galaxy. To do this I wanted to use a dictionary that had lists within for each filter and their respected residual value for all the galaxies I'm working with. Something along the lines of

```py
resid = {}
resid[VIMOSV]['resid'] = 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 1.1, 0.9
resid[VIMOSV]['z'] = 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 1.2
```

so that the key for my resid dictionary is the filter name, followed by another key to pull up residual values or the z values. This is what my code actually looks like:

```py
resid = {}
residval = ((residfiledat[iline]['tempa_zprior'] - residfiledat[iline]['flux_cat']) 
                    / residfiledat[iline]['flux_cat'])
if key in resid:
                        resid[key]['resid'] = np.append(resid[key]['resid'], residval)
                        resid[key]['z'] = np.append(resid[key]['z'], 
                                                    zdat[clustname[iclust]]['spec_z'][goodindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])
                        print('key:' , key , 'exists', resid[key])


                    else: 
                        #now make the dictionary entry because it doesn't exist
                        resid[key]['resid'] = np.array([])
                        resid[key]['z'] = np.array([])  
                        resid[key]['resid'] = np.append(resid[key]['resid'], residval)
                        resid[key]['z'] = np.append(resid[key]['z'], 
                                                    zdat[clustname[iclust]]['spec_z'][goodindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])
                        print('key created', key, resid[key])
```

The values from the residval are from a prior loop that I know works. My error comes from the else statement:
'keyerror Traceback(most recent call last)
else:
resid[key]['resid'] = np.array([])
keyerror: 'FOURSTARKs'

I looked it up and this is basically telling me that the key does not exist, but that was the entire point of the else statement. If the key exists, add the values to it, else: create the key. I clearly don't know how to add a key to a dictionary that has to hold a list so help would be awesome.

Comment: First create an empty dict with the new key: `resid[key] = {}`. Then fill it.

Comment: You can't define a nested dict in one go in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your `else` block is this:

```
resid[key]['resid'] = np.array([])
```

So, let's break it down. You are accessing to `resid[key]` and then accessing to:

`resid[key]['resid']`.

This is the same of doing this:

```
outerKey = resid[key] # fail
outerKey['resid'] = np.array([])
```

As you can see the first line will fail because it does not exists as you checked in your `if` statement. So you need to do:

```
resid[key] = {} # Creates the outer key
resid[key]['resid'] = np.array([]) # Creates the inner key
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As @DarK_FirefoX stated in their answer, it's because of the nested nature of the dictionary.

You could achieve the desired functionality like this, however:

```
resid.update({key:{'resid':np.array([]),'z':np.array([])}})
```

Comment: +1. Just wanted to clarify on the behavior of the double indexing that was being made so there would be a better understanding.

Comment: for sure..think either approach is valid, up to the OP now!